# Rails Rspec view mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am trying to test that when not logged-in, access-controlled URL is redirected to login page. I am using Devise and my Devise model is User.

The spec that I cannot get to work is:

```html
  describe "GET #new without being logged in" do

    it "responds UNsuccessfully with an HTTP 302 status code and login page" do
      get :new
      expect(response).to_not be_success
      expect(response).to have_http_status(302)
      expect(response).to render_template(new_user_session_url)
    end
  end
```

The output of rspec (limited to the relevant part) is as follows:

```
    Failures:

  1) AddressesController GET #new without being logged in responds UNsuccessfully with an HTTP 302 status code and login page
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(new_user_session_url)
       expecting <"http://test.host/users/sign_in"> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/users/sign_in>
     # ./spec/controllers/addresses_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have two questions:
1) how can I get rid of the quotes in the expected path

> `expecting <"http://test.host/users/sign_in"> # (quotes)`

since the redirect is

> ```
>  `to <http://test.host/users/sign_in> # no quotes`
> ```

2) do I understand `expect(response)` right in assuming that a redirect  will be interpreted as a failure with `expect(response).to_not be_success` ?
I would have naively thought that `to_not be_success` would be reserved for invalid URLs. How can I distinguish between an invalid URL and a redirect ?

Thank you.

Comment: Re: 1, i don't think you need to worry about quotes. It is the way rspec logs its output. The problem is not with the quotes. Problem is that, you are expecting response to render the sign in template but instead it is being redirected. So, you may do `expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_url)`

Comment: Indeed, the failure disappears when I apply your change. Thank you very much,@JagdeepSingh